# Is there a way to send events to the parent job when using Start-WPFJob?

Tags: wpf, events, powershell, user-interface, jobs

I would like to launch a non-blocking UI from a parent Powershell script and receive UI messages like button clicks from the child job.  I have this kind of messaging working using WinForms, but I prefer to use [ShowUI](http://show-ui.com/) because of how much less code it takes to create a basic UI.  Unfortunately, though, I haven't found a way to send messages back to the parent job using ShowUI.

#### [Works] Forwarding Events When Using Start-Job

Using [Start-Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx), forwarding events from a child to a parent job is rather straightforward.  Here is an example:

```
$pj = Start-Job -Name "PlainJob" -ScriptBlock {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PlainJobEvent -Forward
    New-Event -SourceIdentifier PlainJobEvent -MessageData 'My Message'
}

Wait-Event | select SourceIdentifier, MessageData | Format-List
```

As expected, it prints out:

```
SourceIdentifier : PlainJobEvent
MessageData      : My Message
```

#### [Does Not Work] Forwarding Events When Using Start-WPFJob

Using [Start-WPFJob](https://github.com/dfinke/powershell-for-developers/blob/master/chapter07/ShowUI/Start-WPFJob.ps1), on the other hand, does not seem to forward events from the child to the parent.  Consider this example:

```
Import-Module ShowUI
$wj = Start-WPFJob -ScriptBlock {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MySource -Forward

    New-Button "Button" -On_Click { 
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier MySource -MessageData 'MyMessage'
        }
}

Wait-Event | select SourceIdentifier, MessageData | Format-List
```

Running this example produces this window:

[image]

Clicking on the button, however, does not yield an event in the parent job.

---

1. Why doesn't the `Start-WPFJob` example yield events to the parent job?
2. Is there some other way to use ShowUI to produce a button in a non-blocking manner and receive events from it?

Comment: Oooh, that's a great question. Or idea.  
I mean, it would be nice if the WPFJob forwarded events, I wonder what's required...

Comment: Forwarding events from WPFJob would open up a whole world of use cases for ShowUI.  MVC applications would become possible in very few lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm playing with it. I'm not sure why you want to do that though. I mean, why do you want events from the UI to go to a different process?  You can stream output ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by streaming output.  I've got a state machine that manages long-running jobs.  The state machine is triggered by a variety of powershell events originating from the .NET framework.  The state machine needs its own thread because it blocks on Wait-Event.  The UI needs its own thread because it blocks somewhere in WPF.  In order for a user to, for example, pause/resume the state machine, events need to get sent from the UI to the state machine runspace...somehow.

Comment: I can't get this working, and I'm going to have to get some help, but not until after the new year ;) I'll post an awful workaround below...

Answer (score 1):

I can't get engineevents to forward properly so far (actually, I can't even get them to do anything, as far as I can tell), I think your best bet is to run the WPFJob, and instead of New-Event, update the $Window UIValue, and then from your main runspace, instead of Wait-Event, use Update-WPFJob in a loop.

I would stick this function into the module (actually, I will add it for the 1.5 release that's in source control but not released yet):

```
function Add-UIValue {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Windows.FrameworkElement]    
        $Ui,

        [PSObject]
        $Value
    )
    process {
        if ($psBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Value')) {
            Set-UIValue $UI (@(Get-UIValue $UI -IgnoreChildControls) + @($Value))
        } else {
            Set-UIValue -Ui $ui 
        }        
    }   
}
```

And then, something like this:

```
$job = Start-WPFJob {
  Window {
    Grid -Rows "1*", "Auto" {
      New-ListBox -Row 0 -Name LB -Items (Get-ChildItem ~ -dir)
      Button "Send" -Row 1 -On_Click { Add-UIValue $Window $LB.SelectedItem }
    }
  } -SizeToContent "Width" -MinHeight 800
}
```

Every time you click, would **add** the selected item to the UI output (if you run that window without the job and click the button a couple of times, then close the window, you'll get two outputs).

Then you can do something like this in the host instead of Wait-Event:

```
do {
  Update-WPFJob -Job $job -Command { Get-UIValue $Window -IgnoreChildControls } -OutVariable Output
  Start-Sleep -Mil 300
} while (!$Output)
```

Comment: OK, I think I finally grok what you're doing.  That _is_ doozy of a workaround, but I think I can encapsulate most of the ugliness away.  Can you clarify this one point for me: After running `$job = Start-WPFJob ...` should I expect results from that `do { ... } while ...` loop event without closing the window?

Comment: The Update-WPFJob command will output the results of Get-UIValue (and store them in $Output, which will stop the loop). You would be able to then do something with the $Output...