# Serial port events are not received until some action is performed

Tags: .net, powershell, webforms, serial-port

On one side, I have an `arduino` connected via USB cable. It calls `Serial.println("ready")` every 100 miliseconds in an infinite loop.

On another side, I have a powershell script with `winforms` gui that has two buttons **Click** and **Close**. The script opens serial port and starts listening to `DataReceived` event.

**Expected behaviour**

When an event is received its message is printed to the console.

**Actual behaviour**

When no actions are performed nothing is printed to the console, but each time I click on the **Click** button I get the following output:

```
GOT VALUE FROM READLINE: ready
GOT VALUE FROM READLINE: ready
GOT VALUE FROM READLINE: ready
GOT VALUE FROM READLINE: ready
Click
```

The same output is produced when I click on the **Close** button.
[image]

**Additional info**

It's as if the process falls asleep until I do some actions. Upon waking up it spits out everything it had received in its buffer. I think it has something to do with how powershell `event queue` works. I'm out of depth here, good sirs.

**Code**

```
function main {
  begin {
    $global:latestPortMessage = ''
    $form = createForm
    $port = createAndOpenPort
  }
  process {
    subscribeToPortEvents $port
    [void]$form.ShowDialog()
  }
  end {

  }
}

##### GUI CREATION HELPERS
function createForm {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  [Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
  $FormStartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
  $form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
  $form.AutoSize = $true
  $form.text = "Serial-test"
  $form.TopMost = $false
  $form.StartPosition = $FormStartPosition
  $clickButton = createClickButton
  $closeButton = createCloseButton
  $form.controls.add($clickButton)
  $form.controls.add($closeButton)
  $form
}
function createClickButton {
  $button = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
  $button.BackColor = "#e66b6b"
  $button.text = "Click"
  $button.width = 100
  $button.height = 100
  $button.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
  $button.margin = 0
  $button.Add_Click({ onClickButton })
  $button
}
function createCloseButton {
  $button = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
  $button.BackColor = "#e66b6b"
  $button.text = "Close"
  $button.width = 100
  $button.height = 100
  $button.location = '100,0'
  $button.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold'
  $button.margin = 0
  $button.Add_Click({ onCloseButton })
  $button
}
function onClickButton {
  Write-Host "Click"
}
function onCloseButton {
  closePort
  unsubscribeFromPortEvents
  $form.close()
}

##### PORT RELATED HELPERS
function createAndOpenPort {
  param($portName = 'COM7', $baudRate = 9600)
  $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $portName,$baudRate,None,8,one
  $port.open()
  $port
}
function subscribeToPortEvents {
  param($port)
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $port -EventName "DataReceived" -Action {
    # $value = $Sender.ReadExisting()
    $value = $Sender.ReadLine()
    if ($value) {
      Write-Host "GOT VALUE FROM READLINE: $value"
      $global:latestPortMessage = $value.substring(0, $value.length - 2)
    }
  } | Out-Null
}
function unsubscribeFromPortEvents {
  $subscribers = Get-EventSubscriber
  $subscribers | foreach-object {
    if ($_.SourceObject.GetType().FullName -eq "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort") {
      Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.SourceIdentifier
    }
  }
}
function closePort {
  try {
    if ($port) {
      if ($port.isOpen) {
        $port.Close()
      }
    }
  } catch {
    logError $_
    dumpError $_
  }

}

. main
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This discussion is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414187/powershell-job-event-action-with-form-not-executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution to my problem, but it feels very hacky. I simply added `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. It fires every 1ms and executes a handler that processes serial port input data and updates GUI if necessary.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Code**

[Github](https://github.com/Manidos/ps-serial-client)

Comment: Your github link is dead... Please provide working code in answers.